# Using Fuzzy matching to filter a DF

Tags: python, filtering

I'm creating a function that filters a dataframe based on how similar it matches to some elements in a list using fuzzy wuzzy.
Here is the function as I have it now.

```
def fuzzy_match_filter(data_frame, match_list):
    filtered_rows = []
    
    for index, row in data_frame.iterrows():
        address = row['address']
        
        # Check fuzzy match percentage with each element in the match list
        match_percentage = max(fuzz.ratio(address, match_address) for match_address in match_list)
        
        if match_percentage < 90:
            filtered_rows.append(row)
    
    filtered_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(filtered_rows)
    filtered_data_frame.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    return filtered_data_frame
```

This is fine for a small dataframe but when I get records over 100k it's way too slow.

What is a more effective way to filter a dataframe for results based on how well it matches some elements in a list?

This solution works but I need something more efficient.

Comment: You can use Joblib for parallelization. It can improve the speed.

Comment: You can check out other methods like fuzz.token_set_ratio or fuzz.partial_ratio, or use other libraries like RapidFuzz, which is similar to FuzzyWuzzy but generally faster.

Answer (score 0):

First, `iterrows` is very slow in itself, so maybe you can improve by using vectorization

```py
def fuzzy_match_score(match_list):

    def get_score(row):

        address = row['address']
        
        match_percentage = process.extractOne(address, match_list, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)[1]

        return match_percentage
        
    return get_score
```

The function above is a closure, returning a function. It is only this way so it can take a parameter with the match_list.

```py
# Apply the function
df['score'] = df.apply(fuzzy_match_score(match_list), axis=1)
# filter the low scores
df = df[df['score'] < 90]
```

as far as accelerating fuzzy wuzzy, the library has some good examples of batch process

https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz

```
pip install thefuzz[speedup]
```

This one is optimized to extract the best match and returns the match and score as a tuple. In the code above I extract the score.

```
from thefuzz import process
process.extractOne(address, match_list, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
```